# Validating Enums in Web api 2 object parameters

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Suppose you send a class-instance to controller and the class has a property of Enum type.

```
public class CoffeeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> OrderAsync(Order request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}

public enum CoffeeType
{
    Latte,
    Mocha,
    Espresso
}

public class Order
{
    public CoffeeType Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If there is an error in the name of enum member in request the application doesn't throw exception. It uses a default enum value instead:

```
{"name":"Dan", 'type':"ocha"}=>{"Name":"Dan", "Type":"Latte"}
```

This seems odd to me.
Why such a behaviour is used?

Is there an elegant way to throw error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brett writed you can use ModelState.IsValid and ModelState will have error.
if you need just throw an error you can use custom media formatter for your type, like:

```
public class OrderJsonFormatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
    {
        public OrderJsonFormatter()
        {
            SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }

        public override bool CanReadType(Type type)
        {
            var canRead = type == typeof(Order);
            return canRead;
        }

        public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
        {
            return false;
        }

        public override object ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
        {
            return this.ReadFromStream(type, readStream, content, formatterLogger, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public override object ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(readStream))
            {
                using (var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
                {
                    var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();

                    if (type == typeof(Order))
                    {


                        try
                        {
                            var entity = jsonSerializer.Deserialize<Order>(jsonReader);
                            return entity;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                         //log error here
                            throw;
                        }
                    }

                    return null;
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

and register it :

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Insert(0, new OrderJsonFormatter());
```

Answer (score 1):

It does this because Enums are based on an integer type , so they will always have a value (value types cannot be null) and will default to 0. Use following workaround

```
public enum CoffeeType
{
    Invalid = 0
    Latte = 1,
    Mocha = 2,
    Espresso = 3
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply validation to your models.  Create an `ActionFilterAttribute` and wire it into your pipeline or decorate your endpoint with it.  Recommend you also consider [FluentValidation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.WebAPI/) as a great library to perform validation.

See `ValidateModelStateFilter` example in [this article](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/custom-validation-in-asp-net-web-api-with-fluentvalidation/) for a great example.